# Broken adding text function in Ajax loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to change the text of each span with the **done_by** class so I used Ajax.

I have to send the ID of each span for some reasons to my display_name.php. The ID is created with two numbers separed by '_' that's why I will use the `.split`

There is my code

```
$('.done_by').each(function()
{
    temp = $(this).attr('id').split("_");

    $.post("../functions/ajax/display_name.php",
    {
      id_case: temp[0],
      id_task: temp[1]
    },
    function(data,status){

        $(this).html(data);                 
        //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });             
});
```

The *id_case* and *id_task* are well send to display_name.php.
I'm not sure about the syntax of `$(this).html(data);`

It display nothing. But the alert(data) send my all that I want. I am almost certain that the syntax is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'this' object is current function it self.
Replace it as follows.

```
$('.done_by').each(function()
{
  temp = $(this).attr('id').split("_");
  var self = this;

  $.post("../functions/ajax/display_name.php",
  {
    id_case: temp[0],
    id_task: temp[1]
  },
  function(data,status){

    $(self).html(data);                 
    //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });             
});
```